# Data are not polled while creating User define metric in stack driver in GCP

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-stackdriver

While creating the user-define metric via filter the data are not polled. But filter returns the results.

Filter and metric used for creating the metric

[image]

[image]

How to create the metrics?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's your case here, (because we can't see the creation timestamp of your metric in the screenshot), but take in account that only new log entries received after creation of metric will populate it.

According to [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) :

> The data for logs-based metrics comes from log entries received after
>   the metrics are created. The metrics are not populated with data from
>   log entries that are already in Logging.

Comment: Thanks for your information. so we cant create a metric for log entries that are already in Logged.